# QT Thread exchange data

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a class which inherits `QThread`, I create several instances of this class and it makes my program multi-thread.

I'm also using slots/signals to exchange data between threads and main thread (threads creator).

I had this:

```
void FoundNewFile(QString SourceDrive, QString Path, QString FileName);
```

This was working perfect.

Now I decided to also share metadata of files, for this, I have my own large struct, so I did:

```
void FoundNewFile(QString SourceDrive, QString Path, QString FileName, MetaData* meta);
```

This `MetaData` is fairly large, contains different data types and have several linked structs.
Now when signals emitted, in main thread, when I try to do:

```
meta->datetime->creationhour;
```

I get access denied error.

1) What I was doing (without MetaData) was right or that one was also wrong?

2) What's solution?

P.S. I tried `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` and `qRegisterMetaType` together, didn't work.

Comment: As @JKSH says, DO NOT inherit from QThread, unless you're planning on changing how Qt handles threads. I suggest you start by reading this article: http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

Comment: I wouldn't be so absolute about not subclassing `QThread`, as long as one knows what it does. The reason to usually avoid it is the classic guideline: *composition over inheritance*. If there's no need for an object to *be* specifically a `QThread`, then it shouldn't be, it should have a `QThread` as member instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Never* implement new slots if you inherit QThread. It will not do what you want. A QThread object manages a thread, but it is not a thread. **Your QThread-derived objects live in the main thread, so their slots will run in the main thread** (not the new thread!)

The correct solution is:

1. Do not subclass QThread. Just instantiate a QThread object.
2. Subclass QObject to create a worker.
3. Instantiate your worker and move it to the new thread, using `QObject::moveToThread()`.
4. Start the QThread.
5. Now, when you use signals and slots, the slots will run in the correct thread.

See the [official QThread documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthread.html) for an example.

Comment: Implementing new slots in `QThread` subclass is just fine, programmer just needs to realize they are slots of "thread controller", not to be confused with code running in the thread. Nothing "never" about it.

Comment: Do you know of any examples where the functionality of the thread _controller_ is extended with a new slot, which is intended to run in the original thread and not in the new thread?

Comment: If overriding `run()`, then adding slots to communicate with the thread via whatever traditional low-level mechanism (say, mutex and condition variable) is a natural way to hide that mechanism inside the `QThread` subclass.